# Why is python giving me an unbound local error on introducing new variable inside function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, compiler-errors, local-variables

```
x = int(input("Enter the input in seconds "))

def checkSeconds(x):
    
    if x >= 86400:
        d = x/86400
        x = x%86400
        
    if x >= 3600:
        h = x/3600
        x = x%3600
        
    if x >= 60:
        m = x/60
        x = x%60
        
    s = x
    
    print(d, ":", h, ":" , m, ":", s)
    
checkSeconds(x)
```

Error :  'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'd' referenced before assignment' 
Please bear with me since I am a beginner and still learning. It says 'local variable 'd' referenced before assignment'. Please let me know how to fix this error.

Comment: please always include in your posts here the exact error you're getting from code, verbatim.  As you say, you're a beginner, and it's all too easy to misrepresent errors or omit some additional details

Comment: @DanielFarrell 'UnboundLocalError: local variable 'd' referenced before assignment' This is the exact error

Comment: its says a lot more than that.  When I reproduce it, it provides a full traceback.  See what I mean?  You are asking for our help, but you're omitting part of the output that you've assumed is not relevant.  I'm not saying this to complain - I'm saying it to improve the quality of your questions, and their answers

Comment: @DanielFarrell I see what you mean! Thank you for pointing that out. I'll edit my question right away

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`d`, `h` and `x` require values even if their corresponding conditionals (`if` statements) aren't true.

There's also a few more things I wanted to show you in an example.

First thing I did was to convert to integers the quotients from the division operations.  Otherwise in this code the hours, minutes, and seconds would also include the fractional parts that you actually want in the remainder.

Second thing I did here was to take out the `input` call and replace it with several hard-coded values below.  This way I don't have to input data over and over again, and instead a few simple test cases that can verify that the code is working for me.  Lots of new programmers love using their keyboard to interact with running code.  There's nothing wrong with that, and it's common in academia to require students to input values at runtime, maybe just to underscore the point that the behavior of the code is *dynamic*.  But in the real world it's  very unusual to actually prompt for interactive input to your programs, mostly because it's inconvenient and prone to data entry errors or inconsistencies.  This is a point of opinion, and I just wanted to expose you to the consideration.

Once I did that, I was able to define a few values which test out a few different scenarios.

`0`: none of the conditions match
`59`: none of the conditions match
`121`: only the minutes condition matches
`3662`: hours, minutes, and seconds match.
`882221`: all units match.

With those changes, we can now run the code and get out numbers we would like

```
def checkSeconds(x):
    if x >= 86400:
        d = int(x/86400)
        x = x%86400
    else:
      d = 0

    if x >= 3600:
        h = int(x/3600)
        x = x%3600
    else:
      h = 0

    if x >= 60:
        m = int(x/60)
        x = x%60
    else:
      m = 0

    s = x

    print(d, ":", h, ":" , m, ":", s)

for x in [ 0, 59, 121, 3662, 882221 ]:
  checkSeconds(x)
```

And since I hard coded the test cases, it's easy to make my results reproducible.

```
$ python3 ./t.py
0 : 0 : 0 : 0
0 : 0 : 0 : 59
0 : 0 : 2 : 1
0 : 1 : 1 : 2
10 : 5 : 3 : 41
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're printing the variable `d` everytime, but it only gets defined if `x >= 86400`, in the rest of the cases the variable `d` does not exist and therefore raises an `UnboundLocalError` exception.

Same will happen with the rest of the variables.

A simple solution for that is setting a default value for all of them beforehand.

```
def checkSeconds(x):
    d, h, m, s = 0, 0, 0, 0
```

Comment: seconds doesn't really need to be set as it's not a conditional and is always set to the remainder of the input.  But there's a strong argument to be made for making that behavior explicit.