# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'img' referenced before assignment, however variable is a function argument

Tags: python

Consider the following Python code snippet:

In utils.py:

```py
...
def get_all_fd(image_id, img, label):
    """Get all feature descriptors of a given image"""
    img_shape = np.array(img).shape
    true_channels
    if img_shape[0] >= 3:
        true_channels = 3
    else:
        # stacking the grayscale channel on itself thrice to get RGB dimensions
        img = torch.tensor(np.stack((np.array(img[0, :, :]),) * 3, axis=0))
    ...
```

In an `.ipynb` file in the same directory:

```py
from utils import *

get_all_fd(0,[1,2,3,4],0)
```

I am getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
c:\some_path\task_0.ipynb Cell 8 line 3
      1 from utils import *
----> 3 get_all_fd(0,[1,2,3,4],0)

File c:\some_path\utils.py:267, in get_all_fd(image_id, image, label)
    264 img_shape = np.array(img).shape
    266 if img_shape[0] >= 3:
--> 267     true_channels = 3
    268 else:
    269     # stacking the grayscale channel on itself thrice to get RGB dimensions
    270     img = torch.tensor(np.stack((np.array(img[0, :, :]),) * 3, axis=0))

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'img' referenced before assignment
```

Other imported functions work perfectly, it's just this one. The error message isn't really helpful here, it says `img` isn't assigned, even though it's an argument to the function. What's happening here?

NB: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65971474/why-is-python-giving-me-an-unbound-local-error-on-introducing-new-variable-insid) seems similar, but as shown in the example, even when I pass a constant value, I get the same error.

Edit: I had tried rerunning the cell after editing, but apparently even rerunning a cell does not reflect edits to the source file. I had to restart the kernel, thereby clearing all variables/imports.

Comment: Where is line 265 in your stack trace?

Comment: You didn't read the traceback, eh? The line it's pointing to doesn't even reference `img`. That should be one of the first things you do when debugging. Then you'd want to make a [mre]. Most of the code here is irrelevant to the problem, and if you were able to repeat the problem from scratch, you'd understand it more and have a better, more specific question to ask, like say, [how to "reimport" module](/q/4111640/4518341)

Comment: @InSync It looks like blank lines are skipped, since line 2 in the cell is also missing. I imagine it was blank before OP edited and added `true_channels`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your trace, the argument to `get_all_fd()` is named `image`. But in your code snippet at the top, it's `img`. Try saving `utils.py` and re-running the code. That should work.

Comment: Nice catch! I imagine OP edited `utils.py` after importing it, which would also explain why the lines don't match up.

Comment: @wjandrea's comment helped me find it: Apparently even rerunning a cell does not reflect edits to the source file. I had to restart the kernel, thereby clearing all variables/imports. Thank you both for your help!

Comment: Happy coding, @KaushikNarayan .